# Does the US hold almost all of the bitcoins?

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts, market, usa

It seems to me that most of the people involved in this bitcoin market are from the US.

Are there any statistics that can confirm this?

Also, related question. If this is indeed true, is it reasonable to think that bitcoin was invented by the US in order to destroy the dollar? The US would win because they hold most of the bitcoins, while superpowers like China, who sit on trillions of dollars, would end up with worthless dollars. Does this make sense?

Comment: There are no precise statistics, but you can make educated guesses about where the BTC are by looking at the trade volumes of large CNY and USD exchanges (and to a more limited degree, the IPs that relay transactions in the network). The rest of your question is mere speculation and any answer would be the same, as such it's not a good fit for StackExchange.

Comment: k.. care to share some of those educated guesses?

Comment: http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/volumepie/ will give you a good overview. I'd personally consider it more likely that non-US people are trading BTC<->USD than non-CN people trading BTC<->CNY, so the distribution shifts away from USD a bit, but that's merely my opinion.

Comment: interesting pies. it looks like there's a bitcoin war between the US and China :D Could my theory be true?

Comment: Well, if I was a government that planned to burn its own currency to get rid of debts, I would make sure that my fallback plan wasn't a transparent network with no regulatory influence.

Comment: you're assuming that all governments have shady intentions :)

Comment: Well, if you think that plotting to "destroy the dollar" does not classify as "shady intentions", I'm really not quite sure what to say. (Hint: Such a plan, if carried out 'successfully', does NOT lead to all Americans living happily ever after while the Chinese are crying because their dollars are worthless)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any specific statistics, but yes, bitcoin is recieved more positively in the US than MOST other countries.

Second question?
***NO.*** Definitely NOT.  The US dollar is made by, well, the US, and the US has no intentions of destroying it.  Bitcoin was created by an anonymous programmer called Satoshi Nakamoto.  If the US wanted to replace the dollar they would probably market it instead of letting it catch on VERY SLOWLY.  And bitcoin is not the future of money.  Don't get me wrong, it *IS* revolutionary, but it isn't the future.  It justisn't fast enough.  Lightning is an L2 so it isn't bitcoin but regardless people would still have to open channels too fast.  So no.